# CSS Transition and animation disappear after the starting animation finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi, 
I have a problem on CSS animation and transition.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".d1").click(function(e){
     $(".d2").css("animation-direction", "reverse");
      $(".d3").css("animation-direction", "reverse");
    });
    
    $(".d2").click(function(e){
     $(".d1").css("animation-name", "none").css("opacity", 0);
      $(".d3").css("animation-name", "none").css("opacity", 0);
    });
    
    $(".d3").click(function(e){
     $(".d1").css("animation-name", "none").fadeOut("slow");
      $(".d2").css("animation-name", "none").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
@keyframes inseq { 
 100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.d1, .d2, .d3 {
  opacity: 0;
 transition: all 2s;
  animation: inseq 3s ease 1s forwards;
}

.d2 {
  animation-delay: 1.3s
}

.d3 {
  animation-delay: 1.6s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1">1</div>
<div class="d2">2</div>
<div class="d3">3</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7mepwmg/2/
    


I have a starting-fade-in animation on a series of elements, and then using jquery click event to trigger fadeout; I have tried 3 methods (in example they are .d1 .d2 and .d3 click event) to achieve so, but none of them can do so while the animation finished.....

P.S. If the animation has not finished yet, they work well...

Do I miss anything ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated this a little.

It has something to do with the `opacity=0` set on the div elements and the use of `animation-direction:reverse`. Tough to explain. Basically it jumps to the initial key-frame without any animation. So I've created another set of keyframes for out animation instead of using `animation-direction:reverse`.

```
@keyframes in {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes out {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0;}
}
.d1,.d2,.d3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: in 3s ease 1s forwards 1;
}
.d2 {animation-delay: 1.3s}
.d3 {animation-delay: 1.6s}
```

And then used this to add the second animation and change the initial opacity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function(e) {
    var selected = $(this).attr('class');
    $('div').not("." + selected).css({
      'opacity': '1',
      'animation' : 'out 3s ease forwards 1'
    }).delay('3000').fadeOut('0');
  });
});
```

Here's the updated Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/thelessergeek/0pwan8qm/

Comment: It works well! Thanks! 
And I also tried to remove the 
`.delay('3000').fadeOut('0');`, 
I found it still works. Why should we include those 2 actions?
You have also mentioned about the key-frame, can I control it directly ??

Comment: that delay and fadeOut adds the `display: none;` attribute after 3s. That is the animation duration. You can remove it if you want. Its not necessary. Just depends on what you want happening. You already are setting the keyframes in CSS. What do you mean by controlling it?

Comment: Thanks again @Ankith Amtange !
What I mean for contolling is accessing a in-between of key-frames in a specific (e.g. 50%) in javascript event or css pseudo-class and play it in the way I want (e.g. click to trigger animate from 50% to 75% and then back to 50%)

Comment: You can check this out. [Controlling CSS Transitions/Animations with JS](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)

Comment: Understood, and now it has already worked better than I expected, Thank you very much @ankith !!